# Defect vs CR - how to distinguish

Tags: testing

Scenario:

Currently we are in the process of system and integration testing. Every day we get lots of defect raised by testers. Most of these defects do not match with requirement we were given. Lots of scenarios are new to developers. Requirement we had was signed off by business.

Could someone clarify how to distinguish between Defect vs CR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Everything that was not a requirement is a change-request.**

*But live is unfortunately not that easy, so please read on.*

Quarrels on what is a defect and what is a change-request are very common in projects. Managing the situation is difficult because you often have to make compromises.

I have seen project managers being removed by programme managers because they insisted to much that all the defects are really change requests. They often were right but still there behavior was not helpful for the overall progress of the programme. I have also seen project managers who killed themselves by accepting every defect and built castles though never originally required and effort estimated for.

I personally always make absolutely sure that my managers know that I am building features not originally required that came in under the disguise of defects. I also make sure the client/tester knows that this is my viewpoint. But also I am very tolerant in my consideration what a defect is.

Example: I recently joint a project where we developed a financial payments system and another programmer said to me "It is outrages what they want have that is not a defect this is a CR!". I looked at it and due to my background in this business domain I thought it actually is very fundamental requirement and asking for a CR for this is really laughable. So I decided we fix it without making a fuss about it.

Also the following questions are worth to consider:

- Are you in a fix price project? Do you still have resources and show real greatness by adding features without moaning that will give you a good reputation and a future contract?
- Do you get penalized if you accept a CR as a defect? Is a low-number of defects a KPI (Key Performance Indicator) and affecting your career?
- Was the requirement definition poor at the beginning and you accepted it? Was the requirement mentioned in the defect real obvious and could be considered implied? E.g. never specified that amount field should only allow numeric values but still it makes sense.
- Have you accepted requirements without asking about the whole big picture and are partially responsible?
- Is the client ripping you off and exploiting your inability to say no and reject the defect?

**In projects I always try to get the best for the client but make sure I am not being penalized undue.**